# Why is this rewrite rule not working?

Tags: asp.net, xml, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I am using ASP.NET URL Rewrite module and wrote this rule :

```
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="test">
              <match url="http://localhost/ElWazefa/User/Ahmed/ahmed.aspx"/>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost/ElWazefa/ahmed.aspx"/>
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

But it doesn't work.

*using asp.net 3.5 and XML IntelliSense for URL Rewrite 2.0*

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code syntax seems to be correct

try to check your URLs for typos or leave the port/host out of the URL like that:
"/ElWazefa/User/Ahmed/ahmed.aspx"

Comment: i made sure that the url is correct also i tried to remove the localhost but still wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

I think your URLs can't include the protocol/host/port portion. Try:

```
  <rewrite>
      <rules>
          <rule name="test">
              <match url="/ElWazefa/User/Ahmed/ahmed.aspx"/>
              <action type="Rewrite" url="/ElWazefa/ahmed.aspx"/>
          </rule>
      </rules>
  </rewrite>
```

Comment: removed the localhost but still no luck